# How to automatically save *txt file while open?(or copy *txt)[C# Visual studio)

Tags: streamreader, streamwriter

Can somebody help?
At first, after button click I chose any *txt file in my PC(using openFileDialog), I open it and program should save it automatically(without file dialog) in BlaBla.txt. Or maybe make copy of *txt file.
I try many ways, all I get is empty *blabla.txt*

```
 if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                   System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);


            string line = sr.ReadLine();

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("BlaBla.txt");
            file.WriteLine(sr);


        }
```

---

**edidet code. Still not work.**

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
                   System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

              String line = reader.ReadLine();

               // System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("ddd.txt");

              //  file.Write(sr);
                   System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("ddd.txt");
                file.Write(sr);
                file.Flush();
            }_____________________________________________
```

**Find another way to save, i`ts works.**

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {


                string org, copy;

                System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                while ((org = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    copy = org.ToString();
                    using (System.IO.StreamWriter files = new System.IO.StreamWriter("blabla.txt", true))
                    {
                        files.WriteLine(copy);
                    }
                }

                file.Close();
            }
```

Comment: You need to add file.flush().  The stream contains a buffer and not until the buffer fill will the write to the file actually occur.

Comment: mhh, and how to correctly add this flush?

Comment: The flush is normal done just before closing the stream, but there are cases where you may need to read the stream before it gets closed and may need to flush the stream just after the writes are performed.

Comment: I edited code, see above. Still not work.

Comment: Are you getting anything in the text file?  What happens if you add a file.Close();?